# Are unlinked redis keys evicted before memory-policy is applied?

Tags: memory, redis

We use [UNLINK](https://redis.io/commands/unlink/) rather than [DEL](https://redis.io/commands/del/) to unload memory release into a separate thread. We also use **volatile-ttl** [`eviction policy`](https://redis.io/docs/reference/eviction/) with a fixed **maxmemory** configuration.

When redis reaches the **maxmemory** limit, there can theoretically be unlinked keys whose memory has not been released yet. Will redis prioritise release of that memory before applying the key eviction policy?